# Inner join cakephp 2?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, inner-join, models

I'm having 2 tables named, users and userdetails. Basicly the query i want to run is:

```
SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN userdetails ON users.id = userdetails.userid
```

I wonder how you could get this done. Im new to cakephp, so i would appreciate a detailed description.

Comment: Man, please, read the docs. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html

Comment: Better link: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Answer (score 0):

got it working right now

merging 2 tables without too much hassle.

```
        $modelmerge = $this->Users->bindModel(array
    (
        'belongsTo' => array
        (
            'Userdetails' => array
            (
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array
                (
                    'Userdetails.userid = Users.id'
                )
            )
        )
    ));


    $users = $this->Users->find('all');
```